# React .map an object

Tags: reactjs, typescript, tslint

I've got an eslint error **Property 'date' does not exist on type 'never'**, and it's on `data.date`. Any idea how can I fix it?

```
import React from 'react'
import app from './../Flamelink'

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState([])
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const data = await app.content.get({
        schemaKey: 'persons'
      })
      setData(data)
    }
    fetchData()
  }, [])
  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(data => (
        <li>{data.date}</li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  )
}

export default App
```

Comment: Are you using javascript or typescript? eslint or tslint? Which IDE?

Comment: Don't call everything data. Use a different variable name each time instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I would use a different variable name instead of just calling everything `data`. This way you avoid [variable shadowing errors](https://palantir.github.io/tslint/rules/no-shadowed-variable/).

If you want your state variable to be `data` then call the answer you get from your fetch something else, `result` maybe. Then, when mapping your `data` state, call the current value something else too, maybe `item` or `dataItem`.

Second, since you appear to be using TypeScript, you need to tell TS the structure of your `data` state array.

Try this:

```
function App() {
  const [data, setData] = React.useState<Array<{date: string}>>([]);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await app.content.get({
        schemaKey: "persons"
      });
      setData(result);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ul>
      {data.map(item=> (
        <li>
          {item.date}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
}
```

Comment: @HimaduSirimanna, what do you mean? How would that protect privacy?

Comment: I get TypeError: data.map is not a function .I am used to display data in UI by importing JSON Data and displaying like div>data.map<h1>{n.data.head}<h1><p>{n.cat.content}.etc. but with your solution can't use that way.... I am also using typescript with ts lint  I'm a new user and a learner so forgive me, i changed everything to data because to  protect data privacy.

Comment: , TypeError: data.map is not a function,

Comment: @HimaduSirimanna maybe `result` is not an array? What is the value?

Comment: As I tagged this use flame link if you heard it and I don't know how the flame link pass data and this is the first time I use flame link,result is data given by flame link and only way I know how to see it is using a console log, also appreciate your help....

Comment: I haven't heard of Flamelink either. Console.log is fine to check the value. Can you check it? What does it show?

Comment: Here a example, [image](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1RJpnMSI837537MD0P6Vo9bYkM3jVW8dh)

Comment: Live example is also available, [link](https://fir-32d38.firebaseapp.com/) , open the console log and look in products part.

Comment: What you have is not an array, but an object. You should change this in your useState also (from `useState([])` to `useState({})`) but most importantly, you need to use `Object.values` to iterate over an object. So instead of `data.map(item =>` you need `Object.values(data).map(item =>`.

Comment: Now I get Object is type unknown.

Comment: @HimaduSirimanna that is a TypeScript error. You can either specify the type of the object with an interface, or just use `any`. The last one would be: `React.useState<any>({})`. It's probably better to use an interface though. You can google how to do that. Sorry, forgot you are using TS.

Comment: Using type object solved the problem, Appreciate your help.

Comment: Okay... And Done.